# How to use Excel to view a proprietary delimited file

Tags: parsing, excel, vba

I have text files that are in a comma delimited format. However, the data is in a format such that there is no way for Excel to infer how to format the data that makes sense to the user (i.e. the built in Import Wizard is not sufficient). Because of this, I think I will need to build a plugin/script/macro/etc that parses the data and then displays it in Excel.

When all is said and done, my goal is to:

1. Open Excel
2. Import the text file from desktop
3. Parse the data
4. Display the data in Excel in a format that makes sense to the user.

Also, whatever solution I end up making, I would like to distribute the solution to other Excel users (i.e. I'm thinking I could send them an Excel Plugin or maybe an Excel Template)

I have never programmatically interacted with Excel before - whether it be a Macro, VBA script, or .NET Office plugin, etc. So, I'm unsure on how to accomplish my goal.

I'm not asking on how to programmatically parse the data nor am I asking how the data should be displayed to the user. My question is in regards to what the "normal" Excel solution is for this type of problem - Is this problem best solved by a Macro, VBA script, or .NET Office Tools, etc?

Comment: If it is comma delimited, I don't see why using the wizard (making sure you have selected the option to use comma as a delimiter) would not work.

Comment: @assylias because the data file consists of subsets of data. The raw data file that I'm working with contains thousands of lines where each line begins with an identifier that tells me what the line consists of. Depending on the line identifier, the line can contain data that is a child of another parent line of data. The bottom line, to make all the line associations manually (Import Wizard) would be practically impossible. The solution needs to be automated.

Comment: If you are planning to distribute the solution like you mentioned above then I would recommend an Excel Add-In created using VSTO.

Comment: A macro is a VBA script - you may have meant a `VBscript` which is a different beast.

Answer (score 0):

I remember when most text file records started with a record type and multi-record type files were common. It is only the limitations of packages such as Excel that have made this practise uncommon.

With the Import Wizard, have you tried accepting the default General format which should cause Excel to parse each field separately?

If that does not work, reading the rows individually and parsing it into fields using VBA is not difficult. I have a routine I would be happy to share. Displaying the data so it makes sense depends on the nature of the data. Please give details.

As an example of how it used to be, one package might share a batch of invoices as a text file with record types:

```
1  Batch header
2  Invoice header            \
3  Invoice line     Repeats  | Repeats as group
4  Invoice trailer           /
5  Batch trailer
```

Each of these records would have its own specification.

I assume your file is something like this.  It would not be difficult to format such data so it looks OK as an Excel worksheet.  I am sure people would be happy to make suggestions if you give more information.